# Point to object in UI from other class - Android SDK

Tags: java, android, class

I've just started development with Android and I have little experience in Java. I've got a button listener in my main Activity but I want to do a background task that updates an TextView in my UI. See the following code.

```
    btnJSON.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            new BGTask().execute(); 
        }

        class BGTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                String x = "test";
                return (String) x;   
            }   


            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                tvData.setText(result);
            }
        }            
    });
```

This code works, however, when I move the code for the BGTask code to a seperate class file, its no longer possible to update the UI component tvData. How do a pass a reference to that object to the BGTask class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, if you want to move your task class to another file, is this:

1. Add a TextView field to BGTask and a constructor that takes a TextView.
2. Pass in the TextView you want to update.

Here is the code:

```
public class BGTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private TextView tvData = null;

    public BGTask(TextView tv) {
        this.tvData = tv;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String x = "test";
        return (String) x;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (tvData != null)
            tvData.setText(result);
    }
}
```

And your activity will look like:

```
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    final BGTask task = new BGTask(tv);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            task.execute();
        }
    });
```